# Не запускается symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony

Если ввести в консоли php "-S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public", то всё работает. Но если проследовать в папку public, ничего не пашет...

Вот такая ошибка "
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv::populate() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Dotenv\void, none returned in /var/www/html/blog_symfony/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php:95 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/blog_symfony/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php(57): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->populate(Array) #1 /var/www/html/blog_symfony/public/index.php(19): Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv->load('/var/www/html/b...') #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/blog_symfony/vendor/symfony/dotenv/Dotenv.php on line 95"

Никто не встречал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, у вас стоит версия php меньше **7.1**, т.к. интерпритатор не может понять что такое `void`.

Вот здесь уже был задан такой вопрос: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/25469

Comment: Я уже решил, бросил симфони, вы, скорее всего, правы, PHP 7.0 был.